# How to distinguish between the Sinatra request object and the Rack Test request method?

Tags: ruby, https, sinatra, rack-test

I have a method that runs in the Sinatra app scope that checks to see if the request is secure:

```
secure_request?
  request.env[ 'HTTPS' ] == 'on'
end
```

This works fine, but when I call it from another class that does not share the Sinatra app scope, it attempts to make an Rack Test request, raising an error: `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`.

So, is there a way to specify the Sinatra app request explicitly, such as `self.request` or `app.request`?

Comment: Is your app a classic or module Sinatra app? Can you give an example of calling that method from another class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling a `request` method from another class smells like poor code design, tightly coupling that other class to your app. Where is `secure_request?` defined? Is it a helper?

I would personally call a method from Sinatra to that other class and pass in the request value, instead of having that other method poll to find out. For example:

```
class OtherClass
  def some_method( opts={} )
    if opts[:secure]
      # …
    else
      # …
    end
  end
end

class MyApp < Sinatra::Application
  helpers do
    secure_request?
      request.env[ 'HTTPS' ] == 'on'
    end
  end
  get '/' do
    @otherclass.some_method( secure: secure_request? )
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. The OtherClass should not know about the Sinatra request.